# How to feed and mulch fruit bushes

Tags: fertilizer, fruits, mulch

I found some good information on looking after fruit trees of types common in the UK here (https://www.rhs.org.uk/advice/profile?pid=539)

Essentially:

1. Clear ground of grass around the trunk
2. Apply appropriate fertiliser in late winter/early spring
3. Apply mulch in later spring

But what about fruit *bushes* - in the UK that would typically mean currants, gooseberries, blueberries for example? Is it all the same or are there species-specific things that need doing?

Comment: The RHS has specific advice in these links: https://www.rhs.org.uk/Advice/Grow-Your-Own/Fruit The generic term to search for is "soft fruits."

Comment: Ah I didn't realise "soft fruit" specifically was used this way

Comment: When I grew red currants , I did not use fertilizer ; mulch probably provided a little. They were still prolific fruit producers . I used some ordinary 10,10,10  on raspberries . Blue berries need rabbit eradicator rather than fertilizer. If you are growing tons of fruit commercially it is different from a few bushes for home use , and fertilizer is more important.